# Is it a good practice to build in as many foreign keys as possible?

Tags: foreign-key

For example, there are three tables: `players`, `dungeons`, and `instances`.

A `player` has many `dungeons` and each `dungeon` has many `instances`, like in a well-known game of World of Warcraft. Each `player` would have a `dungeon_id` as a foreign key and each `dungeon` would have an `instance_id` as a foreign key. That would be a sufficient minimalist approach. A `player` of each `instance` can be accessed through the `dungeon` table. This would result in 1 less column, but a bit longer query.

Another approach is to add `player_id` to `instances` table as a foreign key. Now players can queried directly from `instances` table. Shorter query, but one more column for a foreign key.

Which approach is better in the long run? In practice it seems like adding a foreign key everywhere where it is logically possible makes it easier. But then wouldn't it result in tighter coupling and make code harder to refactor?

Comment: You say that player has many dungeons but you put dungeon_id in players? It seemd you have it reversed. Please clarify the relationships between the entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally *Entities* should not have foreign keys and should be considered [masters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675890/difference-between-master-and-transaction-table). So `player`, `dungeon` and `instance` are masters having informations/attributes/fields related to their own features. You can have a separate table for *Enitity-Relations*. So you would have `player_dungeon` and `dungeon_instance` (both one to many as per the PS).
Here if you want to know `instances` belonging to a `player`, you need to join these two tables.

Now comes the famous debate: normalisation vs denormalisation. The first approach is *by the book* and would work. But it is difficult to scale as the tables grow (inspite of having proper indexes). So you try to denormalise the above solution depending on the volume of queries which are happening on these tables.

> A `player` of each `instance` can be accessed through the `dungeon` table.

As you have specified one query here, I am assuming that is a frequent query (bottleneck). If there are many queries of such kind you can have another relationship table `player_instance`. Now we have solved the problem of latency but given birth to a bigger problem:

**Consistency**: Now there are two ways to find the `instances` belonging to a `player`. One is directly by `player_instance` table, another by joining `player_dungeon` and `dungeon_instance`. We **must** always get same answer from these two approaches. To ensure that we now need to make our *writes* suffer. How?

- On addition of each player-dungeon mapping, apart from entering to our
  `player_dungeon` table we also need to insert into `player_instance`
  table (for which we have to query `dungeon_instance` to see all those
  instances mapped to that particular dungeon).
- On addition of a new `dungeon_instance` we need to map all the
  existing players to that instance which we mapped to that particular
  dungeon. Doesn't sound good, does it?

We are not done yet. All of these operations should be *atomic* (i.e. in a transaction) or else there will be inconsistency for a short while.

Finally we need to make a trade-off. Do you want to make your database *reads* slow or *writes* suffer? Do you need to make your system responsive/available or consistent? The decision is yours to make.

Please read [CAP theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) for details.

Comment: That is a very good answer, thank you very much! Clarified it all for me who never formally studied computer science. I think I'll go with denormalized approach because I'm pretty sure reads will become a bottleneck for me even with moderate scaling.

Comment: @ArthurTarasov, sorry i forgot "one to many  relation at the same time".Read my edited answer.Since you have only 3 table between you and it is really too early to decide about demoralization.

Answer (score 1):

> Another approach is to add player_id to instances table as a foreign
>   key. Now players can queried directly from instances table. Shorter
>   query, but one more column for a foreign key.

IMO, this will be bad approach.This is kind of circular reference  .

Since you have one to many relation so mapping table will be separate,dungeon,instance and player each will have master table and mapping table defining their one-to-many relation.

```
    CREATE TABLE instances (
    instance_id INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,instance VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    )

CREATE TABLE dungeons (
    dungeon_id INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,dungeon VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    )

CREATE TABLE player (
    playerid INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,player VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
    )


CREATE TABLE dungeon_instance (
    dungeon_instance_id INT identity(1, 1)
    ,dungeon_id INT NOT NULL
    ,instance_id INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_instances FOREIGN KEY (instance_id) REFERENCES instances(instance_id)
    ,CONSTRAINT FK_dungeon FOREIGN KEY (dungeon_id) REFERENCES dungeons(dungeon_id)
    ,PRIMARY KEY (
        dungeon_id
        ,instance_id
        )
    )

CREATE TABLE player_dungeon (
    player_dungeon_id INT NOT NULL
    ,playerid INT NOT NULL
    ,dungeon_id INT NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT FK_player FOREIGN KEY (playerid) REFERENCES player(playerid)
    ,CONSTRAINT FK_dungeon FOREIGN KEY (dungeon_id) REFERENCES dungeons(dungeon_id)
    ,PRIMARY KEY (
        playerid
        ,dungeon_id
        )
    )
```

if you have very frequent query between player and instance where there is no dungeon table require in output and volumne of data is high then you can go for Denormalisation.

Whether to create `player_instance mapping table` or not depend upon above requirement.

But it desirable to achieve Denormalisation via `index view`

Comment: Thank you for 'denormalization' reference. I wasn't aware of it.